# How to check login in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication

i have problem with login , when i entered correct username and wrong password the result should not allow me to login but in my case if the username correct and the password wrong it's allow me to login to the application.

here is my login script

```
<?PHP 
include_once("conn.php"); 

    $user= $_POST['userName'];
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $qr="select password from user where userName='$user'";
    $res=mysqli_query($con, $qr);

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

         $pass=$row[0];
      }

        $saltQuery = "select salt from user where userName = '$user'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con , $saltQuery);

         while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
          $salt = $row[0];
         }
        $saltedPW =  $password . $salt;
        $hashedPW = hash('md5', $saltedPW);



    if($pass==$hashedPW){


        $query = "SELECT userName, password  FROM user WHERE userName = '$user' AND password = '$hashedPW'";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

       if($result->num_rows > 0){
     echo"success login ";
   } else{
             echo"failed login ";


      }
```

Comment: Have you set primary key for Username in your data base ?

It looks like you have multiple records with same username and password

Comment: First of all, why aren't you using a single query to get all details instead of 3 queries?

Comment: You should probably not be writing your own login script, if you do not even have the basic debugging skills to analyze such a problem on your own.

Comment: Always set `id` as a primary and as auto-increment..For example one college can have 30 persons named john..

Comment: @AgamBanga because i retrieve the salt and password hashed from database and mix the salt with the password that was inserted by user , if the there is match it's should be login.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something that for login page.

```
<?php
    include("config.php");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    echo $username= $_POST['username'];
    echo $password= $_POST['password'];

    $username = addslashes($username);
    $password = addslashes($password);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);

    $pass= md5($password);
     $seladmin ="SELECT id,UserName,Password FROM login WHERE UserName='$username' && Password='$pass'";
     $SelRecAdmin = mysqli_query( $link,$seladmin );


    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($SelRecAdmin); 

    $tot_num_row=mysqli_num_rows($SelRecAdmin);
    if($tot_num_row >0)
    {

     $_SESSION['adminid']=$row['id'];
         $_SESSION['adminunm'] = $row['UserName'];
        header('location:home.php');
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
     $_SESSION['msg']= 'Invalid username or password';  
    header('location:index.php');
    exit;
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a solution for your question. I didn't run it, if you get any syntax errors kindly fix it by yourself.

**Make sure you don't have same Username in your code, Otherwise it'll show success message if if you enter wrong password. (As per your code ).

But the following code should give you the expected results even if you have multiple entries with same username. **

```
<?PHP 
include_once("conn.php"); 

    $user= $_POST['userName'];
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password = hashIt($password,$user);

    $res=mysqli_query($con,"select * from user where userName='".$user."' AND password='".$password."'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1){
        echo "Login Successfull";
    }else{
        echo "Invalid Username/Password";
    }


function hashIt($password,$user){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"select salt from user where userName = '".$user."'");
    // No need to check other things, if query fails / no records found anyway it'll show login failure message.
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
          $salt = $row['salt'];
    }

    $saltedPW =  $password . $salt;
    return hash('md5', $saltedPW);
}

?>
```